# Vectors which do not belong to column space also pass the test which is the passed by the vectors in column space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**In the book Linear algebra and it's application by Gilbert Strang, it is given that**

We have an augmented matrix for system of linear equations $ Ax=b$ as:
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&5&b_1\\2&4&8&12&b_2\\3&6&7&13&b_3\end{bmatrix}
After applying gaussian elimination:
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&5&b_1\\0&0&2&2&b_2-2b_1\\0&0&0&0&b_3+b_2-5b_1\end{bmatrix}

Description of Column space of A:  **The column space contains all vectors with $b_3+b_2−5b_1=0$.**
That makes $Ax = b$ solvable, so $b$ is in the column space. All columns of $A$ pass this
test $b_3 +b_2 −5b_1 = 0$. This is the equation for the plane (in the first description of
the column space).

My question is this: is correct to say that "The column space of $A$ contains all vectors with $b_3+b_2−5b_1 = 0$"?
I know that all the vectors in column space of $A$ will pass this test $b_3+b_2-5b_1$ but wont there be **vectors outside the column space of $A$ which also pass this test**? So, should we say " the column space of $A$ contains **all vectors which pass the test**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove the converse as well. If $b_3+b_2-5b_1=0$ then we will be able to solve the augmented system with infinitely many solutions and hence $b$ will belong to the column space. As an example, $A[0,0,5b_2/4-3b_1,2b_1-3b_2/4]^T=b$.

Comment: Thanks! this is simple argument to prove it. I was trying to find general equation of the plane formed by column space and proving that there exists a vector [d1,d2,d3] which doesn't belong to this plane of column space and d2+d3-5d1=0.